# Shortening For Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

```
sum_num = 0

for human in humans:
    sum_num += human.limbs
return sum_num
```

Assume object `human` has a attribute `limbs` as in:

```
human.limbs = rand.int(0, 4)
```

What would be a good way to shorten this as we would with list comprehension?

```
sum_num = sum_num + human.limbs for human in humans
```

Obviously, the above raises an error. Is there no way to shorten some for loop like above?

Comment: `return sum(human.limbs for human in humans)` see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: `sum` is a builtin. Make sure you're not replacing it - eg `sum = 0` before you try @StephenRauch suggestion.

Comment: Sorry replace sum with any other temp variable name. Its just a place holder for int values.

Answer (score 3):

The [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function is the Pythonic way to sum.  `sum()` takes an iterable.  In this case, a very helpful iterable is the [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). Generator expressions use (basically) the same syntax as [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  Using `sum()` and a generator expression, what you are trying to do, can be expressed, quite simply, as:

```
sum(human.limbs for human in humans)
```